# Calling As400 procedure in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ibm-midrange

HI All,

I have created one simple stored procedure in AS400. It has only one input parameter and I compiled and created it successfully. Now I need to call this procedure in SSIS to move data from source to destination. Here my source is As400 procedure and destination is Sql server table.I have goggled lot 
to find how to call the procedure in ssis but nothing works on my end . I need some help from you guys.

Thanks
Mushtaq

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linked server you can use the EXEC command to start the procedure from an SQL task. The CALL command should work as the AS400 CALL

EXEC ('CALL LIBRARY.PROCEDURE') AT [LINKED AS400 NAME];

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OLE DB provider for AS/400.

I've used (a looooong time ago) the [Hit Ole DB provider](http://www.hitsw.com/products_services/oledb.html), and it worked great.
Also, you can use [Microsof's Host Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/host-integration.aspx)

I'm afraid both are commercial products. To my knowledge there is no free alternative.

Comment: I believe you could use a ODBC connection instead

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable via the script component.

1. Script component>>Destination
2. Create a User Variable for the connection manager, and call the same in the script component.
3. Write the script to call the stored procedure

This worked for me.

Note: I am using Kingswaysoft tool kit script component.